# Markov process analysis

Tags: probability

How can I find out the probability of a failure of a power plant while it is running at a specific load? For Example, if there is a 300 MW power plant, it has a failure probability when it is running at 300 MW. Also it must have a different failure probability when it is running at 200 MW also. My question is how I can find these probabilities using plant tripping and repair time records.

Comment: What are these "plant tripping and repair time records"

Answer (score 0):

On any given day the power plant can either fail or be ok

$H $ : event that all is ok

$\bar H $ : Failure

For Markov processes we look at the probability as being depending on the event of the previous day.

$H_n $ and $\bar H_n $  Denote failure and success on day n

$Pr(H_{n+1}) = Pr(H_{n+1}|H_n)Pr(H_n) + Pr(H_{n+1}|\bar H_n)Pr(\bar H_n) $

$Pr(\bar H_{n+1}) = Pr(\bar H_{n+1}|H_n)Pr(H_n) + Pr(\bar H_{n+1}| \bar H_n)Pr(\bar H_n) $

As a matrix equation

$\begin{bmatrix}Pr(H_{n+1}) \\ Pr(\bar H_{n+1})\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}Pr(H_{n+1}|H_n) & Pr(H_{n+1}|\bar H_n)\\Pr(\bar H_{n+1}|H_n) & Pr(\bar H_{n+1}|\bar H_n)\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}Pr(H_{n}) \\ Pr(\bar H_{n})\end{bmatrix}$

Note that $H_{n+1}|H_n$ and $\bar H_{n+1}|H_n$ are mutually exclusive events so

$Pr(H_{n+1}|H_n) + Pr(\bar H_{n+1}|H_n) = 1$

and

$Pr(H_{n+1}|\bar H_n) + Pr(\bar H_{n+1}|\bar H_n) = 1$

So

$\begin{bmatrix}Pr(H_{n+1}) \\ Pr(\bar H_{n+1})\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}Pr(H_{n+1}|H_n) & Pr(H_{n+1}|\bar H_n)\\1 - Pr(H_{n+1}|H_n) & 1 - Pr(H_{n+1}|\bar H_n)\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}Pr(H_{n}) \\ Pr(\bar H_{n})\end{bmatrix}$

The remaining unknown probability values will need to be estimated from these "plant tripping and repair time records".

For calculating this many days in advance you may need to use matrix diagonalisation as shown [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#An_application) .

Comment: I presume the 300Mw and 200 mw scenarios will be treated seperately